# Is it ok to target Android 1.5 for my business app?

Tags: android

I am writing a simple business app that retrieves data from a server for very light content. IS there any disadvantage to building this on Android v1.5?

I'd like to make my application available to as many Android devices as possible. I was just wondering if there are any significant performance disadvantages if I build for this target platform and run it to v2.2 or v2.3.

Comment: The targeted SDK isn't what determines performance, it's the runtime. There might have been some performance tuning in the source itself, but the bulk of the speed improvements come from better Dalvik VMs.

Comment: You also need to keep in mind.  Its less than 1%, and its a moving target, so by the time you release, it will be less (and less, and less). (Whoops, this was supposed to go under one of the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what APIs you are using. You may need to make some compromises that might affect performance if you stick to the 1.5 API. Otherwise, as far as performance goes, I think the main thing you'll need to be concerned about is [compatibility mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) with large-screen devices running newer OS versions.

According to [the Android statistics](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html), V1.5 devices represent less than 1% of the market. The market for your app may have different statistics, of course, but I wonder how important 1.5 is to anyone.

A better approach is to design the app, determine what APIs it uses, and then decide whether backward compatibility is worth whatever compromises in app performance or features that would entail.

Comment: +1; beat me to it--screen size is really the only technical issue, and sheer volume (or lack thereof) is the only real ROI issue.

Comment: You can get around the screen issue by setting API level 3 as the minimum and API level 4 (or higher) as the target.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the major disadvantage would be the lack of different screen resolutions.  I *believe* that was a 1.6 and up thing.

There's nothing "wrong" with 1.5, but I'd say you're WAY beyond the point of diminishing returns.  If a client asked us to support 1.5 I'd consider not taking the job ;)  1.6 is the only practical minimum at this point (IMHO, which I sure many will disagree with).

Comment: with 1.6 having only 1.4% of the market (and probably much less when the app is finished), you should already skip that and focus on 2.1 and above...

Comment: Oh, yeah.  totally agree.  With most people I tell them 2.2.

Comment: Android has around 190M activations. 1.4% of this = ~2.66M. That's a lot to throw away without any good reason. 1.5 -> 1.6 was a big leap because of screen sizes, which can justify the decision to focus on 1.6+.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but again.  Moving target.  Plus, if I had to guess, the older phones/OS versions are disproportionately responsible for support issues.  Also, again speculating, but the people who hang on to their phones forever are less likely to buy apps, and probably look for apps less often in the store because few people are baking new ones for old phones.  Having said that, everybody should do what they're comfortable with. I would not support 1.6, but I also don't jog or eat Broccoli.

Comment: @Dororo to use your calculation: if your app is installed on 1% of all devices (1.9M installations), you are stuck to lower API level, no multitouch for 26.600 users that might already looking for a new phone. Even if your app costs 2 or 3 bucks, its barely reasonable to live with the limitations and the support (old devices often results in lower app ratings/comments). Concentrate on the other 1.874M Users :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, don't target 1.5.

Long answer: 1.5 is hardly run by anybody nowadays (see http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html ) and you'll encounter issues when you want to add in some cool neat features that aren't in 1.5 but are in other versions (1.6+). One big issue here is **1.5 does not support multiple screen sizes**. This feature was introduced in 1.6 (using the folders drawable-hdpi drawable-mdpi etc) and as a result, when you specify in your manifest minSdkVersion="3" your application will automatically be run in Screen Compatibility mode (see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html ). You *can* work around this by setting min=3 and target=4, but it will become tedious since there are many other really useful functions you simply won't be able to use in 1.5. Realistically, 1.6 should be the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

You can target 1.5 but you will loss some new features in new Android versions, Also must take in consideration memory management for old android devices.

2.1 and above enough to cover almost the market. [check this](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)